# Plotting average values from multiple columns in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that stores marks for questions against multiple ids.

```
ID, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5
R1,  4,  3,  3,  2,  1
R2,  3,  2,  3,  2,  4
R3,  5,  1,  3,  4,  3
R4,  1,  3,  3,  5,  3
...
...
```

I want to plot the average marks of the 5 questions in a single plot.

How do I go about doing this in R using the ggplot2 package? What would be my 'x' and 'y' aesthetics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-liner with `geom_col`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(mean = colMeans(df), question = names(df))) +
      geom_col(aes(question, mean))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Q1 = c(4,3,5,1), 
           Q2 = c(3,2,1,3),
           Q3 = c(2,2,4,5),
           Q4 = c(1,4,3,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start transforming your data. Here I make a `data.frame` with one column for the labels and another for the averages and then feed it to `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)
col_means <- colMeans(data[paste0("Q", 1:5)])
col_meansdf <- stack(col_means)
col_meansdf
#   values ind
# 1   3.25  Q1
# 2   2.25  Q2
# 3   3.00  Q3
# 4   3.25  Q4
# 5   2.75  Q5

ggplot(col_meansdf, aes(x = ind, y = values)) + 
  geom_col()


# or in one step:
qplot(
  x = paste0("Q", 1:5), 
  y = colMeans(data[paste0("Q", 1:5)]), 
  geom = "col"
)
```

[image]

Reproducible data:

```
data <- read.table(
  text = "ID, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5
  R1,  4,  3,  3,  2,  1
  R2,  3,  2,  3,  2,  4
  R3,  5,  1,  3,  4,  3
  R4,  1,  3,  3,  5,  3", 
  header = TRUE,
  sep = ","
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for such a prompt reply. I am new to R, so excuse my naivety. I was wondering if there is any way to do this without creating a new data frame. My original data frame is quite big and creating a new dataframe would significantly increase analysis time.

Comment: @SouravAdhikari see the second solution marked with the comment `# or in one step:`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `stat_summary` after converting [from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format). Change `geom = "point"` at will, see other possible geoms in `?stat_summary`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

long <- df1 %>%
  gather(Question, Answer, -ID)

ggplot(long, aes(Question, Answer)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = mean)
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.csv(text = "
ID, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5
R1,  4,  3,  3,  2,  1
R2,  3,  2,  3,  2,  4
R3,  5,  1,  3,  4,  3
R4,  1,  3,  3,  5,  3
")
```